# Wordpress Digits Plugin "Invalid Mobile Number" Error While Doing API User Registration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Despite using all parameters mentioned on their documentation (https://help.unitedover.com/digits/kb/rest-api/#authentication ; which is poorly poorly documented if I might add) I'm still getting an error.

They don't have a Github page & their customer response is slooow (thank goodness for Stackoverflow!) What could I be doing wrong?

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": {
        "code": "0",
        "msg": "Invalid Mobile Number",
        "level": 2
    }
}
```

Any help?

They don't mention which parameters are mandatory so I placed *ALL but even then it still fails. Anyone know the correct *format* for mobile numbers?

Comment: I've used this DIGITS WordPress plugin and found it extremely unstable:  whenever they release an update something breaks.  Their support is atrociously slow, (almost non-existent) and I think there's a lot of bugs. I'd suggest looking for a different app.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin for API login and signup too. This is actually because of a faulty code. Digits plugin leverages the same function for API signup & traditional website signup. I will share the fix with you.

- Open digits rest API addon files from the plugin file editor.
  There you can see a function with the name
  `digirest_create_user()`. Inside this function, there is an internal function call with the name `digits_create_user()`. This function is responsible for your user creation.
- Now here is the problem it is not able to process the API requests. You need to copy the `digits_create_user()` from the digits plugin and copy it in your main digits rest API plugin file the same file where you find the `digirest_create_user()`.
- Make sure you copy the function above `digirest_create_user()` function. Once you have copied the function you need to change the function name (it can be anything) now inside the function you will find a line like this -  `$otp = sanitize_text_field(dig_get_var('dig_otp'));` replace this line with this -  `$otp = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['otp']);`
- And inside the `digirest_create_user()` function you will find the following line -  `$data = digits_create_user();` replace this line with  `$data = your_custom_function();` here replace the `your_custom_function()` with the renamed function I said in earlier steps.

This will work if you face any other issues kindly paste your code here so that I can help you out.